# Asp.NET User Control Postback Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a aspx page that has a Tab control, a few buttons and a User Control on it.

```
<dx:TabPage Text="Worker Information" Name="tabWorker">
    <ContentCollection>
        <dx:ContentControl runat="server" SupportsDisabledAttribute="True">
            <uc:WorkerInfo runat="server" OnWorkerLoaded="On_Worker_Loaded" OnWorkerUnloaded="On_Worker_Unloaded" />
        </dx:ContentControl>
    </ContentCollection>
</dx:TabPage>
```

There are 2 custom events on the user control

```
public event EventHandler WorkerLoaded;
public event EventHandler WorkerUnloaded;
```

I have the event handlers in the main aspx page

```
protected void On_Worker_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnNext.Enabled = true;
}

protected void On_Worker_Unloaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnNext.Enabled = false;
}
```

The On_Worker_Loaded event fires without an issue. I can debug and watch the button become enabled. My problem is when the screen loads the button is still disabled. In my aspx page I disable the button:

```
<dx:ASPxButton ID="btnNext" runat="server" Text="Next" Theme="MetropolisBlue" 
                onclick="btnNext_Click" Enabled="false"></dx:ASPxButton>
```

[image]
The 'Next' button is already disabled. This is why you can't really see it. I have framed it with the black outline. When I click that OK button the WorkerLoaded Event fires.

The only other disable is on the On_Worker_Unloaded Event Handler. I don't have it hooked up yet. There is nothing else that causes the button to disable. Any Ideas what I'm missing?

Thanks!

UPDATE

The User Control has a UpdatePanel in it. I don't know if that makes a difference but I thought I would include that. Something else weird happened I noticed. After enabling the button I noticed that if I did a postback the button would be enabled. Does that ring any bells for anyone?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the loaded event is being called before the Enabled=false property is set.

In your debugger check to see whether the Enabled property is already false when the event is called.

Also, what triggers the WorkerLoaded event?

Comment: The aspx page is loaded before anything else is done. The button is already disabled when the page loads. When I click a 'OK' button on the User Control that is what fires the WorkerLoaded event. The event then should enable the Next button. I will edit my post and add a screen shot.

Comment: I don't see anything obvious. Perhaps something unexpected is happening with the page life cycle. In order to debug, I would try changing some other values in the event handler and see if those other changes are visible on the client.

Comment: I added another button and left it enabled. I tried to change the text on that button and it didn't work. I did notice that if I clicked the button after the WorkerLoaded event fired that the text would then change and the btnNext would be enabled. Would this and the fact the buttons on the user control is inside a UpdatePanel a coincidence? Could the update panel have anything to do with the problem?

Comment: Yes, I believe the update panel can only update the server controls inside the update panel. Since the button is outside the update panel, it is not changed until you do a full postback.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I found a solution that works for me. I put the Next button and the Previous buttons inside their own Update Panel. After I did this everything worked without issue. Thanks for all the ideas and help.